# jquery replace the content of a div persistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace the content of a `div` tag with a certain value every 50sec via polling and jQuery. And I would like to access the value of that updated div, so I can save a request to the backend.

My problem is that once the content has been replaced, the browser displays it correctly, however the HTML stays the same as the beginning. I'm afraid this is a rather basic question, but I'm really curious about this.

Here I prepared an example to illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/LJgN6/7/

And you can see it out ot JSfiddle's context to check the final HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/LJgN6/7/show

I would like to achieve a way to have in the **final HTML**(i.e. right click, view page source):

- `num 1.1` replaced with `num 1.2`
- `num 2.1` replaced with `num 2.2`
- ...

Comment: View source shows the source of the page from the server, without changes made by javascript. You can right click and inspect the elements to see the modified html. You're not actually expecting changes made with javascript to change the source of the file on the server, are you?

Comment: page source is source of the page as rendered by server. It is not updated by any change in the DOM after beeing rendered, hopefully... If you want to make some changes in the DOM persistent server side, you need to request server (e.g using ajax) and set logic server side

Comment: you are all completely right, my bad. The problem lies somewhere else in my code. Maybe I should just remove this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you see in the View Source window is the HTML that was sent to the browser *before anything client side was allowed to modify the DOM.* If you want to see the source as it is modified by your javascript, you need to inspect the DOM (IE F12, Firebug, etc.)

If you need to access this value that was inserted earlier, using javascript to access the contents of your element (ie. `$('#number-2').text()`) should return its contents as they are currently in the DOM.

EDIT: Corrected typo

Comment: Indeed, I need to inspect the DOM as you say, but I was getting blank content when accessing `$('#number-2').text`, the problem lies somewhere else in my code, of course.

Comment: it's `$('#number-2').text()` not `$('#number-2').text`

Comment: @Aister: indeed, that was a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already familiar with jQuery so I would go ahead and head over to the extremely helpful API and take a look at AJAX calls. There is plenty of documentation there that will help you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I've got the polling part of the application solved, thanks for the link tho.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. Take a look at my [fiddle of your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/gtr1971/kL4QN/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#number-1').html("num " + 1.1);   
    $('#number-2').html("num " + 2.2);
    $('#number-3').html("num " + 3.3);
    $('#number-4').html("num " + 4.4);

    setInterval(function(){newInfo();}, 3000);

});

function newInfo(){
    var firstDiv = $('#number-1');
    var secDiv = $('#number-2');
    var thdDiv = $('#number-3');
    var frthDiv = $('#number-4');
    var firstDivInfo = firstDiv.text().substr(4);
    var secDivNewInfo = firstDiv.text().substr(4);
    var thdDivNewInfo = secDiv.text().substr(4);
    var frthDivNewInfo = thdDiv.text().substr(4);
    var newNumber = (Math.random() + 1).toFixed(1);
        secDiv.html("num " + secDivNewInfo);
        thdDiv.html("num " + thdDivNewInfo);
        frthDiv.html("num " + frthDivNewInfo);
        firstDiv.html("num " + newNumber); 
}
```